# Framing problem : Show that $\frac{x^2}{yz+1}+\frac{y^2}{zx+1}+\frac{z^2}{xy+1}\leq\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{4} +1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x,y,z\gt 0$ reals and let $x^3+y^3+z^3=4xyz$

Show that :
 $$\frac{x^2}{yz+1}+\frac{y^2}{zx+1}+\frac{z^2}{xy+1}\leq\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{4} +1$$
Can I use Cauchy inequality to solve it ?

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I want your solution please !

Comment: OK. Show your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I added my attempt as an answer !

Comment: After deleting of your attempts this topic would be deleted. I think is not fair it least towards user755533 . Restore please your attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Inequality:

$$\left(\frac{x^2}{yz}+\frac{x^2}{1}\right)\left(yz+1\right)\geq (x+x)^2\implies \frac{x^2}{yz+1}\leq \frac{x^2}{4yz}+\frac{x^2}{4}$$

Therefore

$$\frac{x^2}{yz+1}+\frac{y^2}{zx+1}+\frac{z^2}{xy+1}\leq\frac{x^2}{4yz}+\frac{y^2}{4zx}+\frac{z^2}{4xy}+ \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{4}=1+ \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{4}$$